# changes: filter only changes from OTHER DB-instances

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

My app has a local pouchdb that syncs with a central couchdb.

The app updates model and ui when it receives changes from the changes feed.

This should happen only for changes that didn't happen locally:

When changes happen locally (by the user, in the ui), the app updates the model with the changed attributes. Then it puts (db.put) the updated object to the local pouch-database (which triggers the change event). When the response from the put arrives, the app updates the rev-attribute in the model.

**question 1**: *Is it possible to filter db.changes to only changes that were NOT generated in the local pouchdb instance?*

Because I have found no solution to above question I am now comparing the local model object with the changed doc delivered by db.changes (by comparing the stringified values).

The problem is: The change event from db.changes happens BEFORE the response from db.put arrives! At this moment my app has not yet updated the rev of the model object and this makes it very hard to compare the two objects - they are always different because the rev's are different.

I have to add that the structure of the objects is flexible because users can configure their own data structures. So I cant (easily) just compare the fields that could have been changed. I will have to hack a solution based on this idea if there is no better way though.

So **question 2** is: *Is it possible to have the change event wait until after the response from db.put has arrived?*

I guess I could use a setTimeout but that seems very hacky.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in PouchDB, but it ought to be fixed now: see [this commit](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/commit/c42beb827db4a43a3ac2c7d273ad7f43dab7f517).

Could you try [the nightly build](http://pouchtest.com/nightly) and see if this is still an issue? If so, please feel free to file another issue on Github. Thanks!

**Edit:** To answer your first question, it's kinda tricky. The best approach I think is to insert some information in your document to track where the document was generated. (E.g. you can give your users a random ID using `Math.random()`, store that in localStorage or as a _local doc, and then include that in each document.)

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try adding ID's to documents to filter the changes stream. I am using pouchdb via npm so I'm not keen on trying the nightly build

Comment: yep, adding an ID of the local DB-instance to changed docs and filtering these docs from the change-stream works nicely